# Select with composite key match my sql

Tags: mysql, sql, key, composite

I have following problem. I want to select single record from my table. That table has composite primary key. This select is in stored procedure that accepts two int parameters.

This is my query:

```
    SELECT @test := 1 FROM MyTable
        WHERE col1 = param1 AND col2 = param2;
```

col1 and col2 are composite key. In short, i want to select one row that match my composite key column values. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which DB are you using ?

Comment: And what is wrong with your query ? Doesn't it give a correct result if you replace `SELECT @test := 1` with `SELECT *` ?

Comment: My query returns value of last row in col1 eaven if the combination of keys do not exists